# How write a mixin in SCSS so that it can be accessed without @include?

Tags: css, sass, mixins, bem, scss-mixins

I am using a wonderful mixin that turns SASS to CSS using BEM methodology.

SASS:

```
=e($name) 
    #{&}__#{$name}
        @content
        
=m($name) 
    #{&}--#{$name}
        @content


.hot // block
    +e(item) // element
        margin: 0
    +m(green) // modifier
        color: green
```

at the output we get CSS according to the BEM methodology:

```
.hot .hot__item {
  margin: 0;
}
.hot .hot--green {
  color: green;
}
```

I am migrating to SCSS. So I need to rewrite the existing SASS mixin into the same short SCSS mixin.

```
@mixin el($name) {
  #{&}__#{$name} {
    @content
  }
}

@mixin mod($name) {
  #{&}--#{$name} {
    @content
  }
}

.hot {
    @include el(item) {
        margin: 0;
    }
    @include mod(green) {
        color: green;
    }
}
```

But it's not as laconic as it was...

How write a mixin in SCSS so that it can be accessed **without @include?**

Comment: Short anwser: you can't.

Comment: @Arkellys very sad( thx